# Swipe settings in El Capitan Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, trash, archive, macos

This is a different question from [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194756/swipe-to-archive-instead-of-delete-in-mail-app-on-el-capitan).

Is anybody able to develop a Terminal command that will change the behaviour of swipe settings in Mail?

By default **swipe right** is 'Mark as Unread/Read' while **swipe left** is 'Trash'.

The Preferences setting is only able to change the **swipe left** gesture to 'Archive' instead of 'Trash'. However no such customisation is provided for the **swipe right** gesture.

I want to be able to **swipe right** to Archive; it feels more natural and moreover this is the setting on my iPhone as well.

Comment: [Airmail 3](http://airmailapp.com/features) has the capability to customize all swipes to whatever you want from a larger list of options. I realize this doesn't answer your exact question but it's an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say there is no hidden setting to do this.

I tried making a new user account and switching the primary language to Arabic - so that the text and mail panes are laid out right-to-left instead of left-to-right and the swipe gesture is still:

- swipe to right marks as unread/read
- swipe to left is trash

My thinking is that if there was an allowance for differing behavior, Apple would have implemented that change in the swipe for languages with right-to-left text flow direction.

I could be wrong and hope someone posts a better answer if I am actually wrong in my guess. My thinking is you'd want to file a bug report to ask for the change if you don't think Apple will re-evaluate this design choice on their own accord.